# Flutter model using for loop

Tags: flutter, loops

i want to do the looping so that "NovelChapter"s chapter_01.txt increment so i dont need to write again and again like below and the Sypnosis stays like that

```
import 'novel_chapter.dart';

class Novel {
  String image;
  String judul;
  final List<NovelChapter> chapters;

  Novel(
    this.image,
    this.judul,
    this.chapters,
  );

  static List<Novel> fetchAll() {
    return [
      Novel(
        'assets/images/ofseaandfire.png',
        'Of Sea and Fire',
        [
          NovelChapter(
            'Synopsis',
            'novels/ofseaandfire/Synopsis.txt',
          ),
          NovelChapter(
            'Chapter 1',
            'novels/ofseaandfire/chapter_01.txt',
          ),
          NovelChapter(
            'Chapter 2',
            'novels/ofseaandfire/chapter_02.txt',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

any solution? or maybe an answer that can help and maybe sharing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's very simple, just generate**

```
class Novel {
  String image;
  String judul;
  final List<NovelChapter> chapters;

  Novel(
    this.image,
    this.judul,
    this.chapters,
  );

  static List<Novel> fetchAll() {
    return [
      Novel(
        'assets/images/ofseaandfire.png',
        'Of Sea and Fire',
        List.generate(10,(index){
          return  NovelChapter(
            'Chapter $index',
            'novels/ofseaandfire/chapter_01.txt',
          );
        }),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: fetchAll method you can provide an int parameter to make it more flexible

Comment: do you have any idea so that i just need to reference that from the folder?